# AutoTextcomplete in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I want to do autosuggestion in textarea
Here is the code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nocfrtj8/)

Now I want apply some other keywords on same textarea which adds sq. braces around the word..
here is the code:

```
    //AUTO SUGGESTION OF SECTION
    $('#textbox').textcomplete([
    {
        words: ['Ceilings', 'Door and Frame', 'Fittings', 'Flooring'],
        match: /\b(\w{2,})$/,
        search: function (term, callback) {
            callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
                return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
            }));
        },
        index: 1,
        replace: function (word) {
            return '[['+word + ']] ';
        }
    }
]);
```

but this doesnot work..please any suggestion

**UPDATE**

This wont show suggestion for other applied keywords..type `Cei`..Wont get any suggestion for that
try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nocfrtj8/1/)

Comment: It works for me Firefox 38.0.5. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I work for me on latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: try to add both textcomplete() function and then type `Cei` ..you wont get any suggestion for `Ceiling` @suvroc

Comment: @hungndv use both texcomplete() function and then type `Cei`..Ceiling wont come..

Comment: You should execute `$('#textbox').textcomplete()` only once

Comment: @suvroc If I want to use those keywords with sq. braces then how to do it??

Comment: use `return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? '['+word+']' : null;` in your callback.

Comment: @PrabhuVigneshRajagopal in 2nd function there are some preserved keywords which can be inserted with braces and other normal keyword will be inserted as it is..if I do as per you said then it will add braces in normal keywords also..I want to use both words array but return different if normal words then print as it is otherwise with braces